# Best way to animate arrow levitating over notification area in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, window, shapes

At some point in my app the main window closes and the application continues to run as a system tray icon.

Whenever this happens, I want to show the user, that the app is now in the notification area as an icon. I could just show a tooltip, but it's not cool anymore.

Instead, I want to levitate a big arrow over an icon, to be sure that the user sees it.

Here is how it's done in DropBox application:

http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/9364/arrowva.png

What is the best way to create and animate this arrow in WPF:

1. A custom shape window? If so, what will do the animation. Can I apply storyboard animation to a window itself?
2. A transparent larger window, but with arrow as an Image, and animate it with storyboard? But than, I will have the window capture mouse clicks, which is not desired.
3. Some other approach?

Thank you.

Comment: I was just wondering about the very same thing. If any of you DropBox developers are out there, care to shed some light on how you did it (the arrow from the DropBox installer looks great, good job!)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Popup` with explicit position:

```
<Popup AllowTransparency="True" IsOpen="True" Placement="AbsolutePoint"
       HorizontalOffcet="{x:Static namespace:TrayInfo.LocationX}"
       VerticalOffcet="{x:Static namespace:TrayInfo.LocationY}" >
    <views:YourViewWithAnimatingArrowImage DataContext="{Binding ifYouNeed}" />
</Popup>
```

[TrayInfo](https://bitbucket.org/rooks/folder-observing/src/18bf3ee1d43e/CommonWpf/TrayInfo.cs)

Answer (score 0):

since u can't really animate a window, (it's a user32 thing, not a wpf element), I'd go with option 2.